# Ошибка при создании процедуры: ORA-01744: неподходящее INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть две таблицы. Первая `EQUI` (Оборудование):

[image: Колонки]

[image: Данные]

Вторая таблица `REST` (Рестораны):

[image: Колонки]

[image: Данные]

Мне необходимо написать процедуру поиска ресторана с минимальной стоимостью оборудования.

Я написал следующее:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE min_rest
IS minprice NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
    select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice
    from rest r, equi e
    where 
        r.equi_id = e.eid 
        and
        e.eprice = (SELECT MIN(eprice) into minprice FROM equi);
END;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/40      PL/SQL: ORA-01744: неподходящее INTO
Errors: check compiler log
```

Может кто-то подскажет, в чем у меня ошибка?

Причем, если я пишу просто SQL запрос, то все работает:

```
select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice
from rest r, equi e
where 
    r.equi_id = e.eid 
    and
    e.eprice = (SELECT MIN(eprice) FROM equi);
```

[image: Просто запрос]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SELECT INTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90) это отдельный вид запроса. `INTO` нельзя использовать в подзапросе, можно только в запросе верхнего уровня. Поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Впрочем, это не единственная проблема в процедуре:

1. Вообще непонятно зачем выбирать `minprice` в переменную. Переменная нигде не используется в дальнейшем. Проще написать подзапрос также как в SQL.
2. Запрос `SELECT` посреди процедуры сам по себе ничего не делает. :

   a. Если нужно вернуть данные по ресторану в отдельных переменных, то нужно объявить аргументы процедуры (`p_rid`, `p_rname` и т.д.), записывать данные в них с помощью `SELECT INTO`.

   б. Если нужно вернуть список минимальных ресторанов, то почитайте как вернуть из процедуры курсор в Oracle.

   в. Если нужно распечатать данные о ресторане(-ах), то почитайте как пользоваться пакетом `dbms_output`. В любом случае потребуется использовать один из способов а) или б).

> *Из комментариев:* Вызываться без каких либо параметров, она должна просто осуществлять поиск ресторана с минимальной стоимостью оборудования и выводить его. ВСЁ!!!!!!!!!!! (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

«Выводить» я понял, как выводить в выходной поток БД. Вполне может быть что имеется ввиду что-то другое, например то, что у процедуры будут OUT параметры, через которые будут возвращены данные.

Примерно так будет работать с курсором:

```
create or replace procedure min_rest is
begin
  --Ресторанов с минимальной ценой может быть несколько
  for r in (select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice
              from rest r, equi e
             where r.equi_id = e.eid
               and e.eprice = (SELECT MIN(eprice)  FROM equi)) loop
    --Выводим каждый          
    dbms_output.put_line(r.rid || ', ' || r.rname || ', ' || r.rcity || ', ' ||
                         r.rplaces || ', ' || r.eprice);
  end loop;
end min_rest;
```

А так с отдельными переменными:

```
create or replace procedure min_rest is
  v_rid     rest.rid%type;
  v_rname   rest.rname%type;
  v_rcity   rest.rcity%type;
  v_rplaces rest.rplaces%type;
  v_eprice  rest.eprice%type;
begin
  --Если ресторанов с минимальной ценой будет несколько, 
  --то произойдет ошибка
  select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice
  --заполняем переменные
    into v_rid, v_rname, v_rcity, v_rplaces, v_eprice
    from rest r, equi e
   where r.equi_id = e.eid
     and e.eprice = (SELECT MIN(eprice) FROM equi);
  --выводим переменные
  dbms_output.put_line(v_rid || ', ' || v_rname || ', ' || v_rcity || ', ' ||
                       v_rplaces || ', ' || v_eprice);
end min_rest;
```

Comment: Потому, что если я убираю into 
то он не говорит что в этом предложении SELECT ожидается фраза INTO
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Речь идет о верхнем `SELECT`, в котором (`select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice`) Туда и нужно добавлять `INTO`. Перечитайте п. 2 в ответе.

Comment: а можете привести пример, как это сделать?

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Для этого нужно определиться с тем что должна делать Ваша процедура. Написано «... процедура поиска ресторана с минимальной стоимостью оборудования ...», но нужны детали: как она будет вызываться, как должны возвращаться данные?

Comment: Вызываться без каких либо параметров, она должна просто осуществлять поиск ресторана с минимальной стоимостью оборудования и выводить его. ВСЁ!!!!
Ни каких параметров, ни каких заморочек, тот sql запрос который я приводил в вопросе мне нужно оформить процедурой

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Накидал примеров

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чем была ошибка

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

О причине ошибки с путями её обхода уже подробно написано в [ранее данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247595).

Из [комментария к нему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247589/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-intobd-oracle-pl-sql#comment2190602_1247595):

> Вызываться без каких либо параметров, она должна просто осуществлять поиск ресторана с минимальной стоимостью оборудования и выводить его. ВСЁ!

Это можно довольно просто сделать, вернув открытый курсор неявно:

```
create or replace procedure min_rest is
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for
        select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice
        from rest r
        join equi e on e.eid = r.equi_id
        where e.eprice = (select min (eprice) from equi);
    dbms_sql.return_result (rc);
end min_rest;
/
exec min_rest

ResultSet #1
[Тут будет вывод результата работы процедуры]
```

---

Если неявный возврат результата нежелателен, или версия БД старше 12c, то тот же самый результат можно вернуть явно с одним параметром вывода (или преобразовав в функцию):

```
create or replace procedure min_rest (rc out sys_refcursor) is
begin
    open rc for
        select r.rid, r.rname, r.rcity, r.rplaces, e.eprice
        from rest r
        join equi e on e.eid = r.equi_id
        where e.eprice = (select min (eprice) from equi);
end min_rest;
/
var rc refcursor
exec min_rest (:rc)
print rc
```

---

**Заметка об ограничении ответственности:** так как структура таблиц и данные в вопросе приведены картинками, не представляется возможным проверить на отсутствие ошибок.